# MULE-4:VM: Check number of messages in VM queue before consuming

Tags: mule4

We required to consume messages from VM in a flow. Currently it is throwing an error when VM is empty as below:

```
Message : Tried to consume messages from VM queue 'FQ' but it was empty after timeout of 5 SECONDS Payload Type : org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider
```

For now we wrapped it in try catch block and handling this error(still it is printing the error stack trace, we want to avoid it)

**I want to check is there a way or piece of code that can be used for checking the number of messages available in VM before consuming it.**

Comment: As given below now we are not seeing error stack trace in logs. I am keeping the question open for few more days to see if I can get logic to check number of messages available in VMqueue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `logException` attribute on the error handler so the exception is not printed in the log.

Example:

```
    <try doc:name="Try">
        <vm:consume doc:name="Consume" config-ref="VM_Config" queueName="q1" />
        <error-handler >
            <on-error-continue enableNotifications="true" logException="false" doc:name="On Error Continue" type="VM:EMPTY_QUEUE">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="consume timeout"/>
            </on-error-continue>
        </error-handler>
    </try>
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it.

Comment: Yes it works, now the stack trace is not getting printed.